# Expedia API showing "cannot service this request.Authentication failure" error

Tags: php, xml

I am new in EAN development. I am developing hotel booking system in PHP using EAN. I want to fetch the reservation details from EAN API.

Following is my code:

```
$itinerary = xxxxxx;
        $cid = 55505;
        $minorRev = 13;
        $apiKey = "y2dfnyvwbwkvgth76hfjdej7";
        $locale = "en_US";
        $currencyCode = "USD";
        $customerSessionId;
        $customerUserAgent;
        $customerIpAddress;
        $url = "http:api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/";
        $urlBook = "https:book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/";

        $url = ($service == 'res') ? $urlBook : $url;
        $url .= $service
                . "?minorRev={$minorRev}"
                . "&cid={$cid}"
                . "&apiKey={$apiKey}"
                . "&customerUserAgent=" . rawurlencode($customerUserAgent)
                . "&customerIpAddress={$customerIpAddress}"
                . "&customerSessionId={$customerSessionID}"
                . "&locale={$locale}"
                . "&currencyCode={$currencyCode}";

        $xml = "
        <HotelItineraryRequest>
            <itineraryId>{$itinerary}</itineraryId>
            <email>customer@mail.com</email>
       </HotelItineraryRequest>
        ";

        $curl = new Curl();
        $info = $curl->exec($xml, $url, "ItinerarySearch");
        print_r($info);
```

It showing the following error : 
**Cannot service this request.Authentication failure**

What is the problem with this code. Is there any solution that how can I get Reservation details from EAN.

I use the demo php code library from expedia : http://developer.ean.com/code_library/samples/PHP_Booking

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will u able to find any solution . i am getting error when i am sending request to book a rooms.

Comment: @rahularyansharma : I Tried the following sandbox: `http://devhub.ean.com/V3sandbox/itineraryForm.asp` it helped me.